# IEnumerable<Twitter Status> View Output MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter, tweetsharp

I am trying to output a set of tweets with a certain hashtag.

I have the following code in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Test() {

        var service = new TwitterService("xxx", "xxx");
        service.AuthenticateWith("xxx", "xxx");

        var options = new SearchOptions { Q = "#test" };

        TwitterSearchResult tweets = service.Search(options);
        IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> status = tweets.Statuses;
        ViewBag.Tweets = status;


        //var tweets = service.Search(options);

        return View();
    }
```

I want to output the results that are in the IEnumerable in a view.
But I am finding it difficult to output these results in a view. Can anyone help please?

Comment: What problems are you having (and you have not even shown you view code)?

Comment: I am stuck, I don't know from where I should start to display this!

Comment: Start by deleting `ViewBag.Tweets = status;` and use `return View(status);` then in the view use `@model IEnumerable<TwitterStatus>` and use a loop to display what you want for each item in the collection

Comment: I think that using return View(status) would result in a View with only the Twitter feed, right? I don't want my view to contain only the feed.

Comment: Then create a view model containing a `IEnumerable<TwitterStatus>` property and pass that to the view. Your question is both unclear and too broad. You need to do some research to understand the basics of MVC and come back when you have a specific problem

Comment: Apart from that, when I tried to add @model IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> to the view it says "the type or namespace name could not be found". P.s. complete beginner at MVC

Comment: Then add a `@using yourAssembly`, or use `@model IEnumerable<yourAssembly.TwitterStatus>`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague but I think I understand your problem.

You'll want to pass the data into your view from your action.

```
public ActionResult Test() {

    var service = new TwitterService("xxx", "xxx");
    service.AuthenticateWith("xxx", "xxx");

    var options = new SearchOptions { Q = "#test" };

    TwitterSearchResult tweets = service.Search(options);
    IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> status = tweets.Statuses;


    //var tweets = service.Search(options);

    return View(status);
}
```

Notice I pass in the status object into the view.

Now in your view you can just bind that object.

```
@model IEnumerable<TwitterStatus>

@foreach(var status in Model){
    <div>
        @status.Id @*Id is an exmaple property. Use the actual properties inside "TwitterStatus"*@
    </div>
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to have multiple things inside your page you'll have to use Partial Views.

You'll need a view that will encompass all your other partial views. To do this, just define a action for your twitter info that will be your parent view.

```
public ActionResult AllInfo() {
    return View();
}
```

Then your razor:

```
//AllInfo.cshtml
@Html.Action("Test", "YourController")
```

In AllInfo.cshtml we call the action "Test" inside "YourController". We'll change "Test" to return a PartialView instead of a View.

```
public ActionResult Test() {

    var service = new TwitterService("xxx", "xxx");
    service.AuthenticateWith("xxx", "xxx");

    var options = new SearchOptions { Q = "#test" };

    TwitterSearchResult tweets = service.Search(options);
    IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> status = tweets.Statuses;

    return PartialView(status);
}
```

The razor stays the same for your partial view:

```
//Test.cshtml
@model IEnumerable<TwitterStatus>

@foreach(var status in Model){
    <div>
        @Model.Id @*Id is an exmaple property. Use the actual properties inside "TwitterStatus"
    </div>
}
```

You can call @Html.Action() as many times as you want in your AllInfo.cshtml page and add all the PartialViews you need.